# Why text(rich) field can't be accessed by site guest users?

Tags: community, lightning-community

I created a site using Salesforce. And I created a community so that guest user can visit the site.
But everything is ok except the text(rich) type field. These fields can't display unless we log in the salesforce.

Related screen captures show below:

when I login:
[image]

when i am a guest user:
[image]

The head photo field type is text(rich);

Another example:
When I log in the system:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

When I am just a guest user:
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

The content of the department doesn't show. And the field type of the content is also text(rich) type.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: OH……I can't post the last two scrennshot cause i don't have 10 reputations……

Comment: does your guest user profile have permission to view the field? do you have any console errors when loading the page using the guest user profile?

Comment: How to know whether guest user have permission to view the field? No console error is found.

Comment: your guest user is associated to a profile (or should be). what kind of community is this? lightning?

Comment: yes, it is a lightning community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the User Guest Profile has access to the field

as mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_public_access.htm&type=0):

> Whenever you make a community using the Community Creation wizard, Salesforce automatically creates a guest user profile for the community

assuming you enabled public access through setup from your community builder:
[image]
you should be able to select the guest user profile link and manage what the user has acces to.